# Probability of 300 members in a health club

Tags: probability, statistics

A health club has 300 members and operates a gym that includes a swimming pool and 10 exercise machines. According to a survey, 60% of the members regularly use the exercise machines, 50% regularly use the swimming pool, and 25% use both of these facilities regularly.

```
     a.) what is the probability that a random chosen member regularly uses exercise machines or the swimming pool or both?
     b.) what is the probability that a random chosen member does not use any of these facilities regularly?
```

How I solved for

a.) EM = 60% of 300 = {180}, SP = 50% = {150} EM&SP = 25% = {75},

so for question a, I'll assume it asks for the probability of a random member using at least one, exercise machines or swimming pool.

EM + SP - EM&SP = 180 + 150 - 75 =

255 of 300 or 85% of people use either exercise machine, swimming pool, or both

I do not know if this is correct or have anyway of checking the answer currently so I am just wondering if I did this correctly, I notice that it gave me the amount of exercise machines they have (10) and i did not take this information into account when i solved the problem..

for question

b.) since, 85% use the facilities, I can say that 15% of 300 people does not use the facilities, so 45 people?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.  It doesn't matter how many exercise machines they have.  For b, you should give the answer to the question that is asked, which is $15\%$. Although $45$ is correct, it is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these answers are correct.